# How to get the token balance(rmrk) by py-substrate?

Tags: balances, assets, python, token, statemine

I want to get the token balance of RMRK in the chain statemine with py-substrate.

Answer (score 3):

```
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface

ASSET_ID = 8  # RMRK.app
ACCOUNT = '<<YOUR_ACCOUNT>>'

substrate = SubstrateInterface(url='wss://statemine-rpc.polkadot.io')
account_info = substrate.query(
    module='Assets',
    storage_function='Account',
    params=[ASSET_ID, ACCOUNT],
)

print(f'Balance: {account_info["balance"]}')
```

Comment: Is there full doc about how to use substrateinterface?

Comment: Sure, you can always check its repository: https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface. It also has a Github page here: https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-interface/

Comment: .Hi, The doc is very simple and can't help me. Can you help me to solve some issues? How to send a rmrk transaction ? I define the: call_module = "Assets" and call_function = 'transfer', call_params = {
        "id": 8,
        "target": target,
        'amount': amount,
    }. But when I call "substrate.create_signed_extrinsic", the error "ValueError: Element "asset_id" of struct is missing in given value".

Comment: Without the whole code is hard to get it but maybe do what the error is point out? Like replacing `"id": 8` by `"asset_id": 8`?